Can't use Entity Framework Core with Supabase (PostgresSQL)
I was trying to move my project from local to remote database.
I've created an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project. I've installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.20, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.20, and as database provider, I used Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 7.0.18.
This setup works fine with local database in PostgreSQL v16, but not with Supabase, where PostgreSQL v15 (just to be clear).
I've got connection string, which worked fine in PGAdmin. And seems EF Core also could use that connection string in this format:
Host=[hostname];Port=6543;Database=postgres;Username=postgres.[my_username];Password=[my_password]

because when I tried to run next command
dotnet ef database update

to perform code-first approach, I've run into this error:

Failed executing DbCommand (32,194ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
"MigrationId" character varying(150) NOT NULL,
"ProductVersion" character varying(32) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY ("MigrationId")
);
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt

And, the most interesting part, the table was actually created, but EF Core somehow did not manage to continue working. And if I try to rerun command again and again, it simply returns the same error.
I tried to use a .NET 8 project with respective updated versions of packages, but that doesn't help.
I also tried to add connection string params
CommandTimeout = 30, Keepalive = 30


Please check whether you are using a VPN or other proxy tool? Make sure that you can connect to postgressql normally using the database connection tool, and whether the connection string is correct?

Im having the same problem with .NET 8 and a freshly setup project.

I fixed it be using the session mode on port 5432 instead of the transcation mode: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/connecting-to-postgres#how-connection-pooling-works

Switching to session mode fixed it for me as well. Now to investigate how to get transaction mode to work since I'll be using this in a serverless environment...

@Chris Did you find the solution how to make this work with transaction mode?
